# WinForms designer: Add control and make it visible for the designer

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a WinForms user control `Host` with a custom UI Editor. 
Through that editor, a child control (`Child`) can be added to `Host`.

(The UI Editor creates `Child` and sets `Child.Parent = Host`)

Child is handled through a `Holder<Child>` helper class, which is set as `Tag` property of e.g. a ListViewItem.

The respective code - some of it, at least - gets added to the form: Holder is created, and set as Tag, which is enough to be created at runtime, too.

However, Child is not visible to the designer - it is displayed, but it can't be selected, nor does it occur in the drop down list with controls for the parent form.

I would like to:

- see the `Child` control in the designer, so that I can modify properties
- get notified if the control is removed

Is this possible?

---

**[edit]** Thanks all for your input. I've decided to skip the designer - I hoped to throw together something quickly, but apparently it requires more planning than I should allow myself to spend on it right now.

Comment: The default UserControl designer already does a lot of this.  How you broke it is quite unclear.

Comment: If your attempting to add controls dynamically, and then edit them through the designer, that is impossible, if thats not what you meant then please clearify

Comment: @sniperX: The TAB control allows to add pages, and then edit them through the designer - so I'd assume it is possible.

Comment: @petercen, Well I'm sorry, cannot add tab pages *DYNAMICALLY* and edit them in the designer, as that happens after the code is compiled.

Comment: @sniperX: of course, in design mode.

Comment: @peterchen The TAB Control is by design a container/host which uses internal TabPages, which are also containers : explanation and code for the TabPages ability to be design-time containers, and accept drag-drop of new controls, while being hosted in another container, is explained in the answer in Henry Minute's article on CodeProject in my answer to you below. It's not trivial, but it will work. Chapter #26 of Matthew McDonald's book on WinForms, "Pro .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and Custom Controls," titled "Advanced Design-Time Support," would also be of real help to you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use`this.Controls.Add(/*Instance of the child*/);` on the host class. Then for the notification add event handler for the host's ControlRemoved event (`this.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(Host_ControlRemoved);`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I fully understand exactly what you are trying to do.

If you are dealing with the problem of how a "child" Control of a UserControl placed on a Form at Design-Time can be made to function as a container onto which you can drag-and-drop other controls from the Toolbox : this CodeProject article by Henry Minute may be helpful : [Designing Nested Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/NestedControlDesigner.aspx). For example : you have a UserControl with a Panel inside it : an instance of the UserControl is placed on a Form : in the Design-time view of the Form : you want to be able to drag-drop controls onto the Panel in the UserControl and have them become child controls of the Panel : Henry's article will show you how to do that.

This from Microsoft : [How to make a UserControl object acts as a control container design-time by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813450)

Perhaps might also be useful, although it seems like you already have this step accomplished.

Comment: @Designing nested Controls - added to my "Designer cheat sheet"